# How to delete the last token in the system.out.println?

Tags: java, output, token

I have this snippet of code and the output is coming out to be `4x^3 + 3x^2 + -5x^0 + 3x^5 + 4x^4 + 1x^3 + -4x^2 + 4x^1 + 2x^1 + -5x^0 + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + -4x^0 + 4x^3 + 5x^4 +`.

Can someone please help get rid of the last `+` at the end?

Here's the code:

```
public static void Iterate(PolyDS result) { 

    NodeClass node = result.getFirstNode();

    while(node!= null) {


        System.out.print(node.getCoeff() + "x" + "^" + node.getExpo() + " + ");
        node = node.getNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
System.out.print(node.getCoeff() + "x" + "^" + node.getExpo() + " + ");
node = node.getNext();
```

to

```
System.out.print(node.getCoeff() + "x" + "^" + node.getExpo());
if(node.hasNext()) System.out.print(" + ");
node = node.getNext();
```

Ideally you should use something like `while(node.hasNext())`.

Comment: This seems to make sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Rose no worries, please don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

One option is to peek ahead to the next value of `node` in the loop, and to print a connecting `+` only when the next node is not `null`:

```
NodeClass node = result.getFirstNode();

while (node != null) {
    String msg = node.getCoeff() + "x" + "^" + node.getExpo();
    node = node.getNext();
    msg += node != null ? " + " : "";

    System.out.print(msg);
}
```